# "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, exception

#### Background info

I'm maintaining a Winforms application in C# using VS2010. The main form has a TabControl with a few tabs. The startup object is a class with a Main funcion (nothing new here) that does nothing more than firing the main form.
The form creates a Datastore object that gets it's connection string to the DB server from a static Settings class. This class has a static intializer block:

```
static Settings()
    {
        IniReader reader = new IniReader("config.ini");
        //...
    }
```

The configuration file resides in the main project folder (same as the startup object) (and also in the bin and debug folders).

#### Problem

In solution explorer, when I double click the main form to open it in the designer, VS crashes with the exception mentioned in the title of this question, but also with an error stating that it can't find the config.ini file in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE".
The problem can be resolved by copying the config file to that location, but I don't find this a real solution.
**Why would VS search for the file in that location?**
Strangely, the last time I opened the solution, I didn't have this problem. I haven't installed new Windows updates since then.

#### *Remark*

*The architecture of the application and other design decisions aren't mine. I'm just extending the program and while doing this, I'm trying to improve on the architecture. But that's not the subject of this question.*

Comment: I would guess that if the path to the config file (defined in the .csproj file) doesn't exist then VS defaults to it's own working directory. It sounds like you have corrected the path in the project file and now it can be located. You could check your source control logs to see if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already understand that the VS designer creates an instance of the form it's trying to show, and that means it will invoke the constructor and any static constructor.

The most common pattern I've seen for avoiding this kind of problem is to move any non-trivial initialisation logic into a separate Initialise method.  In there, and in any method other than a constructor, you can use...

```
if (!DesignMode)
{
    //your code here
}
```

...around any code that isn't actually needed for the form to render correctly in the designer.  I realise that means some refactoring of the code and you may not want to do that, but I have used this approach and it avoids this kind of problem well.

Comment: Thank you. I've been trying this out and at least I got a different error. I guess I'm on the right track.